# Discord.py interaction bug(or i am just dump)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i am trying to make a simple discord bot using a weather API.

but a bug(or something) won't let me

```
@bot.command(name='teste')
async def button(ctx):

    try:

        msg = await ctx.send('Escolha a forma preferivel para inserir a localização',
                             components=[[Button(label="Cordenadas", custom_id="cord", style=4),
                                         Button(label="Cidade", custom_id="button2", style=1)]],
                             delete_after=60)
        cords = await bot.wait_for("button_click", check=lambda i: i.custom_id == "cord")
        cord = len(str(cords.user))
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await msg.delete()
        api_key = 'its my litle secret'
        if cord > 0:
            await ctx.send('informe as cordenadas desejadas(Latitude e Longitude nessa ordem), ex:"$38.9041 -77.0171"')

        city = await bot.wait_for("button_click", check=lambda i: i.custom_id == "button2")
        cit = len(str(cords.user))
```

when i run the code, the button appears normally, when i click i the cord button, he detects, but when i click in the city button, he don´t detect, i figured out that the first `await bot.wait_for` just don´t let the next one be checked, so when i click city he checks the `cord.bot.wait_for` and can´t continue to te next one. Can someone tell me whats hapening and help me to fix this?

don´t mind the portuguese texts.

Answer (score 0):

First, it sounds like you understand your wait_for issue, and you delete the message before running the city button code. To fix that move the delete code to the end.

I found this code in another post, instead of wait_for, it has an on_button_click. This can also be edited for multiple uses. I have added a snippet for how you could set this up.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_button_click(interaction):
    if interaction.component.label.startswith("Default Button"):
```

This should work for you.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_button_click(interaction):
    if interaction.component.label == "Cordenadas":
      #Your Code Here
    elif interaction.component.label == "Cidade":
      #Your Code Here
    else:
      #Run Some Error Code Here
```